# ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found in python code

Tags: python

**Following is my code which I am executing**

https://github.com/federico-terzi/gesture-keyboard/blob/master/learn.py

After executing the code I am getting,

File "learn.py", line 57, in

```
number = ord(category) -ord('a')
```

> TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found

How can I fix it?

Comment: by putting something in `category`, which seems to be an empty list.

Comment: Also, please read the [guidelines on how to write good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the code should all go in the question, links to github should be avoided (because they might break anytime)

Comment: I am a newbie to this world so please pardon my mistakes. Its urgent to solve the query. Will take care next time :)

Comment: Reading that link is a very good starting point for beginners ;) Your problem gets solved much quicker if people actually have a clear view of your code, what goes wrong and where/how

Comment: Instead of saying you'll take care next time, you should edit the question to include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the project data directory contains many files whose filename starts with `_` like `_sample_t10_34.txt`.

So in your code

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        category = name.split("_")[0] # here category = ''
```

Now the next line is:

```
number = ord(category) - ord("a")
```

here as [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) takes an argument of type `str` of length 1, you get this error, as category would sometime be an empty string `''`, when files with name `_sample_t10_34.txt` is beign read.

what you can do is skip files which starts with `_`, by checking with an `if statement` whether the file doesnt starts with `_`.

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if not name.startswith('_'):
            # code here after if statement
            category = name.split("_")[0]
            number = ord(category) - ord("a")
            # rest of code..
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I am getting new error,  IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: on which line ?

Comment: If I am putting,                                                                                           
 if not name.startswith('_'):                                                                 
before line "filename = os.path.join(path, name)"                                                  then I am getting,                                                                                   
   File "learn.py", line 47
    filename = os.path.join(path, name)
           ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: You have to indent code from that line till `classes[number] = category` with 4 spaces(recommended).

Comment: Simple solution is delete all the files which starts with _ in the data file & problem is solved :) Rest all the code will be according to the github link provided above.

Comment: @AjeetYadav the solution above doesnt read files with name that starts with `_`, so basically its the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you linked to, `category` comes from

```
category = name.split("_")[0]
```

and `name` comes from:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
```

So my guess that you have a file name with a leading underscore.  Splitting this string on `'_'` this will give an empty string for the first value of the list.  Example:

```
s = '_abc_test.txt'
s.split('_')
# returns:
['', 'abc', 'test.txt']
```

The zeroth element of this is an empty string which is getting passed to `ord`.

Comment: You get it right. Can you please help me where should I make changes in the code to make it work? My sample file name is "a_sample_0_1" which goes on in series.